# How to avoid "&" to underline next letter?

Tags: winforms

I have a label which I want `T&D` to be its text.

But instead it shows `TD` with the letter `D` underlined.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double the ampersand to escape it.  T&&D should display T&D at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the UseMnemonic property of labels and textboxes are set to True.  This is the property that underlines the following character to act as a hotkey.

Just set the property to False the control will not use the & to underline.